# AWS S3 automatic object key name normalization to lower case

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

AFAIK, object names on AWS S3 are always case sensitive and it is impossible to configure AWS S3 to be case insensitive.

So, is it possible to configure something like AWS Lambda in order to normalize uploaded file names to lower case? Or what is the best practice to perform this task with AWS S3?

Comment: You could write a renaming lambda to get triggered every time a new file was uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is easily done by having a Lambda function subscribe to your S3 PUT Event.

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "s3": {
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "object": {
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901",
          "key": "HappyFace.jpg",
          "size": 1024
        },
        "bucket": {
          "arn": bucketarn,
          "name": "sourcebucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          }
        },
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH",
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789"
      },
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "eventSource": "aws:s3"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then grab event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name and event.Records[0].s3.object.key to make a [copyObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html) request to AWS

Once your file has been copied successfully, you can then [delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html) the original file.

Just make sure your Lambda is configured for PUT events only, because if you set it to ALL events, both COPY and DELETE will also trigger your function, making you enter in an infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks, @Wai Ha Lee for removing the "Hope this helps" sentence. I did not know it was not allowed/well accepted.

Comment: Sorry - I should have left a bit more of a comment instead of doing a drive-by edit. Yeah, salutations and things like 'hope that helps', etc. [are considered 'fluff'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/284827) so it's best to not include them.